# Iptables netfilter packets flow with policy routing

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, netfilter, iproute

I have questions about the order of events in the routing/iptables pipeline. I first explain my setup. The questions are at the end of this post.

I use policy routing and iptables on Linux 4.4.

I have two interfaces: wan0 (towards my ISP) and vpn-crypto (a tun device towards a vpn provider)

I want to selectively route some traffic to the vpn, everything else trough the wan0

I implement policy routing as follows:

- In the mangle OUTPUT table I set a mark 0xC for NEW traffic which
  match some pattern. For testing purpose I mark traffic directed to
  a specific IP address (37.9.239.33). Of course I also have other iptables stuff, like MASQUEARADE, but that is irrelevant to this question.

  I have an iproute2 rule which dispatches all "marked" packet to the
  vpn:

  `0:      from all lookup local
  190:    from all fwmark 0x4/0x4 lookup vpn
  400:    from all fwmark 0x8/0x8 oif wan0 unreachable
  32766:  from all lookup main
  32767:  from all lookup default`

  The vpn table contains only one rule and send everything via the vpn:

  `default via 10.33.0.1 dev vpn-crypto  proto static  src 10.33.148.125`

I test using the command `ping -c3 37.9.239.33` where 37.9.239.33 is an IP address marked for vpn. Two tcpdump sessions, attached to wan0 and vpn-crypto, show that the packet effectively goes out and come back via vpn-crypto, as expected! So far so good, everything works.

I observe however a weird behavior which I do no understand while logging packets flow through iptables: I insert log traces in the FILTER.OUTPUT table and in the MANGLE.POSTROUTING table.

I observe this sequence of events:

`FILTER.OUTPUT:      IN= OUT=wan0 SRC=59.189.21.112 DST=37.9.239.33 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=26960 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=9649 SEQ=1 MARK=0xc
MANGLE.POSTROUTING: IN= OUT=vpn-crypto SRC=59.189.21.112 DST=37.9.239.33 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=26960 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=9649 SEQ=1 MARK=0xc
MANGLE.POSTROUTING: IN= OUT=wan0 SRC=59.189.21.112 DST=37.9.239.33 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=27049 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=9649 SEQ=2
FILTER.OUTPUT:      IN= OUT=wan0 SRC=59.189.21.112 DST=37.9.239.33 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=27100 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=9649 SEQ=2 MARK=0xc
MANGLE.POSTROUTING: IN= OUT=vpn-crypto SRC=59.189.21.112 DST=37.9.239.33 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=27100 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=9649 SEQ=2 MARK=0xc
MANGLE.POSTROUTING: IN= OUT=wan0 SRC=59.189.21.112 DST=37.9.239.33 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=27193 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=9649 SEQ=3
FILTER.OUTPUT:      IN= OUT=wan0 SRC=59.189.21.112 DST=37.9.239.33 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=27237 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=9649 SEQ=3 MARK=0xc
MANGLE.POSTROUTING: IN= OUT=vpn-crypto SRC=59.189.21.112 DST=37.9.239.33 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=27237 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=9649 SEQ=3 MARK=0xc`

1. I expect the re-routing decision due to the mark in MANGLE.OUTPUT
   to happen before FILTER.OUTPUT, but it seems to happen after! In fact, all FILTER.OUTPUT packets are still routed via wan0, indicating no re-routing decision has happened yet. The documentation available on the web is split 50/50 about this point.
   For instance:

   - https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html, 
     chapter 6, table 6-2, states the re-routing decision happens before filter.output
   - http://www.aptalaska.net/~jclive/IPTablesFlowChart.pdf, states the re-re-routing decision happens after filter.output

   Which one of the two is correct? Can someone shed some light on this?
2. In the context of the 3 pings, in the MANGLE.POSTROUTING table I see 2 unexpected packets routed via **wan0**, which are "unmarked" and seem to be
   duplicates of the ones routed via **vpn-crypto**. Why is this? Also, according to tcpdump, this packets never get to the interface (which is correct).

   Can someone shed some light on this behaviour?

Comment: As far as I understand the [linked flowchart](http://www.aptalaska.net/~jclive/IPTablesFlowChart.pdf), the green `OUTPUT` chain illustrates the `mangle` table as  preceding the `filter` table.

Comment: yes, I agree that mangle.output precedes filter. My first question is, does the re-routing decision happens before or after filter.output?

Comment: I have been searching the whole internet and I cannot find an answer for your question either. I am very interested in understanding if any Routing Decision takes place after the Filter's Output chain.